# Extracting firmware image from binary

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, linux, arm, binwalk

I have firmware file in .bin format, but I need get firmware.img image file and Kernel uImage file for reflashing bricked device. How can I get these parts?

I used Binwalk to extract content, `binwalk -e file`:
it extracted two binaries, 8.5MB with 180188.squashfs extension and another binary 3.1MB, and squashfs-root directory with subfolders.

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
392           0x188           uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xEF73A583, created: 1969-12-31 23:59:59, image size: 1572736 bytes, Data Address: 0x20008000, Entry Point: 0x20008000, data CRC: 0x3661C6EC, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "SP2Xcybertan_rom_bin"
13596         0x351C          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 2019-04-03 05:25:36
1573192       0x180148        uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x9053B22D, created: 1969-12-31 23:59:59, image size: 8474624 bytes, Data Address: 0x0, Entry Point: 0x0, data CRC: 0xFC8655E0, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: Filesystem Image, compression type: none, image name: "SP2Xcybertan_rom_bin"
1573256       0x180188        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 3.1, size: 8473072 bytes, 1028 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2019-04-03 05:36:06
```

Download [file](https://yadi.sk/d/RUyYX1B9Gk8-Wg).